# Generate property selector expression for POCO property

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class:

```cs
public class User 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to generate a list:

```cs
List<Expression<Func<User, object>>> selectorExpressions = /* ... */
```

That list is supposed to hold selector expressions for every property that match this example lambdas:

```cs
user => user.Name;
user => user.Age;

/* etc... */
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

**EDIT**: To clarify: I want to generate this list for every property in a class, e.g. something like this:

```cs
List<Expression<Func<User, object>>> selectorExpressions = Util.GetSelectorsForEveryProperty<User>();
```

I don't want to manually write lambdas for every property I need.

Comment: `selectorExpressions.Add(user=>user.Name)`. You don't need reflection for this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't want to have to manually write lambdas, I want to generate expressions for every property in class, see edited answer.

Comment: Merhat posted how to do that but why do you want to do that? That sounds similar to eg Automapper or what a serializer would need. There may be a solution already. Going too meta while trying to make things "flexible" has the opposite result

Comment: Did you try to create a single expression that accesses a property? When you have done this, do it in a loop for all properties. Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just need to automate some querying in my backend and want expressions so EF could properly translate it... Don't want to go into specifics...

Comment: @mrpyo you'll have to, for this to make sense. You don't *need* to specify those expressions at all with EF, it will use the anonymous type in the `.Select` operation to generate whatever it needs itself. If you want to construct a query using UI settings like order, visible columns etc, you don't need to prepopulate the list either. Grid components use such functionality by the way. So do OData controllers

Comment: @mrpyo the specifics matter.  I've been down that rabit hole and it's not trivial. If you can find an existing implementation you'll save a *lot* of time. If the fields, order etc come as parameters. On the other hand, writing the lambda by hand is no more work (and no less flexible) than writing a configuration file but *using* it is a lot easier. Writing and validating a configuration file can be a lot slower and harder than changing a LINQ query too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you need to know, then yes, among other thing I need it for the grid view and filtering and sorting, and obviously existing component would be best, but surprisingly with Razor Pages there is a scarcity of existing solutions... Also, like you said with existing solution you often sacrifice flexibility for the need of writing (often quite complex) configuration. Of course I could move to SPA where support is much better, but it's not feasible for the small project that I'm working on.

Comment: @mrpyo I need to know because I've seen such code in commercial ASP.NET MVC libraries like Kendo UI. An SPA wouldn't help - whether you use jquery, fetch or any other technique, in the end you'll send a `query` object to the controller action that contains the entity names, fields, sort order, paging information. From that the library's mapping code will generate a LINQ query.

Comment: @mrpyo have you considered using OData? OData controllers work that way already and ASP.NET Core became available recently BUT it's too flexible. The backend developer has no idea what the front-end will do which makes optimizing queries difficult. Imagine eg someone trying to load customer and product data separately since there's no direct relation. Or creating a *client-side join* between customer, order and product. That's why people move to GraphQL instead.

Comment: @mrpyo this means that a) you can steal the code used in ASP.NET Core OData controllers but b) you should investigate GraphQL too, eg through [GraphQL.NET](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/). It gives the backend developer control of the overall schema/shape but allows the UI to specify fields, conditions and order very easily

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SPA would help in that sense that I've seen libraries that offer filtering, sorting and pagination but they focus entirely on Web APIs. Sadly, adapting them to server-side rendering seems to be more work than it's worth... Although I will check what they are doing behind the scenes, logic should be the same after all... good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via reflection and dynamic expression creation:

```
var selectorExpressions = new List<Expression<Func<User, object>>>();

foreach (var prop in typeof(User).GetProperties())
{
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "x");
    var property = Expression.Property(arg, prop.Name);
    var cast = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, object>>(cast, arg);                
    selectorExpressions.Add(expr);
}
```